# Getting what comes after a certain string - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a config, but I need to know what to replace, so I have a line looking like this:

```
Status = Online
```

But it's not always "Online", so I need to know what it says. So basically I have a string "Status = Online", and I need to know what comes after "Status = " and get it returned as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String`-methods like `IndexOf` and `Substring`:

```
Dim text = "Status = Online"
Dim textAfterStatus As String = Nothing
Dim indexOfStatus = text.IndexOf("Status = ")
If indexOfStatus >= 0 Then
    textAfterStatus = text.Substring(indexOfStatus + "Status = ".Length)
End If
```

`IndexOf` returns `-1` if the substring was not found. That's why i check if it's `>= 0`. The overload of `Substring` with a single parameter returns the substring behind that index. I need to add `"Status = ".Length` because you don't want to include that text.

Another option is to use `String.Split`, if you only care about what comes after the `=`:

```
Dim textAfterEqualSign As String = text.Split("="c).Last().Trim()
```